# Struggling to display the right values in power bi with calculated columns

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I'm facing an issue with displaying my values in a card visual. I have a calculated column that shows the margin of the values I'm looking for. I would like to display in a card visual the sum of my margins from month to month, i.e., margin January + margin February or margin March + margin May, and so on.

To give you some context, my margin column is calculated as follows: margin 2022 vs 2021 = `[gap 2022 vs gap 2021] * [CA 2022]`, where the column gap 2022 vs gap 2021 is defined as DIVIDE(gap 2022 - gap 2021, 100).

Following the picture below the numerical values in green correspond to my gap 2022 vs 2021, the first being for the month of May and the second for June. The ones in blue represent my margins 2022 vs 2021 for the months of May and June.

The number in gray corresponds to -266695.04 + (-11207.45): It's this number that I want to display, but Power BI is returning a different value.

[image]

Best regards.

I tried to call my margin columns in a measure using the TOTALYTD function but the values are not what i'm expecting on the picture above

Comment: Your question is quite cryptic and hard to follow. If you share a sample or mock pbix, it would help us to help you. Or provide clear data in the question (in the form of markdown table) as well as your measures/columns, data model, relationship etc... So many factors for us to consider.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.